# Android fragment lifecycle: onResume called twice

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, lifecycle, onresume

I am trying to save and restore scrolling in my fragment after user switches to another activity and then returns to the current one.
Here is what happens:
[image]

As you can see straight after first fragment's onResume goes onPause, although user does not do anything.

The question is : What is wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

```
public class DisplayNoteActivity extends Activity {

private Context mContext;
//static final int SUBACT_EDITNOTE=100;
private long m_NoteID;
private String m_sTextNoAbbrev;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try
    {
        Log.v("DEBUG", "DisplayNoteActivity.onCreate()");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_note);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        m_NoteID = extras.getLong("DisplayNote_NOTEID");
        m_sTextNoAbbrev = extras.getString("DisplayNote_TextNoAbbrev");

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            RefreshFragment();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.v("DEBUG", "DisplayNoteActivity.onSaveInstanceState()");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putLong("DisplayNote_NOTEID", m_NoteID);
    savedInstanceState.putString("DisplayNote_TextNoAbbrev", m_sTextNoAbbrev);
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    Log.v("DEBUG", "DisplayNoteActivity.onRestoreInstanceState()");
    m_NoteID = savedInstanceState.getLong("DisplayNote_NOTEID");
    m_sTextNoAbbrev= savedInstanceState.getString("DisplayNote_TextNoAbbrev");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.v("DEBUG", "DisplayNoteActivity.onResume()");
    super.onResume();

    RefreshFragment();
}


private void RefreshFragment()
{

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putLong("DisplayNote_NOTEID", m_NoteID);
    bundle.putString("DisplayNote_TextNoAbbrev", m_sTextNoAbbrev);

    android.app.FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    DisplayNoteFragment dnf = new DisplayNoteFragment();
    dnf.setArguments(bundle);
    ft.replace(R.id.container, dnf);

    ft.commit();
}}
```

Fragment code:

```
public class DisplayNoteFragment extends Fragment {


private Context mContext;

private long mNoteID = 0;
private Note m_NoteData;

private long mTextID = 0;
private int m_levels = 0;

private String m_dbtype;
private String m_dblang;
GitaTextsHelper m_tdb;

private String m_sTextNo;
private ScrollView m_Scroll;
private int mScrollPos=0;

AutoResizeTextView m_atvHeaderTitle;
AutoResizeTextView m_atvHeaderSubTitle;

AutoResizeTextView m_atvBookTitle;
AutoResizeTextView m_atvChapterTitle;
TextView m_atvTags;
AutoResizeTextView m_atvVerse;

TextView m_tvGitaText;
ImageView m_NoteTypeIcon;
ImageView m_EditNoteIcon;
TextView m_tvNote;

int m_titlePrefixID;


long m_TextRowID = -1;
String m_sVerse;

public DisplayNoteFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_note, container, false);
    Log.v("DEBUG", "DisplayNoteFragment onCreateView()");
    try {
        m_Scroll = (ScrollView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ScrollView02);
        m_atvHeaderTitle = (AutoResizeTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.header_title);
        m_atvHeaderSubTitle = (AutoResizeTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.header_subtitle);

        m_atvBookTitle = (AutoResizeTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
        m_atvChapterTitle = (AutoResizeTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chapter_title);
        m_atvTags = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.note_tags);
        m_atvVerse = (AutoResizeTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.note_verse);

        m_tvGitaText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gita_text);
        m_tvNote = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.note_text);

        //***** INPUT
        mNoteID = getArguments().getLong("DisplayNote_NOTEID");
        m_NoteData = MyApp.mUserDB.GetNote(mNoteID);
        // common fields for text notes and custom notes
        m_atvHeaderSubTitle.setText(m_NoteData.sCreatedDate);
        m_NoteTypeIcon = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.note_type_icon); m_NoteTypeIcon.setImageResource(MyApp.getNoteTypeIcon(m_NoteData.type));
        //tags
        String tags = MyApp.mUserDB.getNoteTags(mNoteID);

        if (tags.equals("")) tags = MyApp.Res.getString(R.string.no_tag_defined);
        m_atvTags.setText(tags);
        m_atvTags.setPaintFlags(m_atvTags.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        m_atvTags.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (MyApp.mC.hasFlag(Cookies.FL_Tagging, mContext, true)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, TagEdit.class);
                    intent.putExtra("TAGEDIT_NOTEID", mNoteID);
                    intent.putExtra("TAGEDIT_EDIT_TAGS_MODE", 1);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rootView;
}

private void openText(int iScroll) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DisplayText.class);
    intent.putExtra("rowID", m_TextRowID);
    intent.putExtra("Scroll", iScroll);
    intent.putExtra("Language", m_dblang);
    intent.putExtra("DBType", m_dbtype);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mScrollPos=m_Scroll.getScrollY();
    Log.v("DEBUG", "DisplayNoteFragment onPause(). Scroll="+mScrollPos);
}


public void onResume() {
    Log.v("DEBUG", "DisplayNoteFragment onResume(). Scroll="+mScrollPos);
    super.onResume();
    if(mScrollPos!=0) {
        m_Scroll.scrollTo(0, mScrollPos);
        Log.v("DEBUG", "DisplayNoteFragment onResume(). Scrolled to="+mScrollPos);
    }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if(outState==null) return;
    Log.v("DEBUG", "DisplayNoteFragment onSaveInstanceState(). Scroll="+mScrollPos);
    outState.putInt("mScrollPos", mScrollPos);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState==null) return;
    mScrollPos = savedInstanceState.getInt("mScrollPos");
    Log.v("DEBUG", "DisplayNoteFragment onActivityCreated(). Scroll="+mScrollPos);
}
```

}

Comment: because of RefreshFragment();  you are calling from Onresume

Comment: I guess his intention is to refresh fragment UI elements on all transactions

Comment: I could not find a better way to refresh data in fragment's fields after user edits data. That is why I was calling RefreshFragment() from activity's onResume(). Can you point me to the correct way of doing it? Could not google it so far...

Comment: Add the RefreshFragment() method to the "SAVE" button listener (if you have one somewhere), when the user makes some changes to the fields and hit the save button you can refresh the UI

Comment: I dont have such a SAVE button. Editing happens in another activity, which saves changes to the database. After I get back to my DisplayNoteActivity, I need to refresh fragment with new data in the database

Comment: in my application `fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();` was the source of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragment is getting replace twice that's why onResume of Fragment getting called twice. You should call your RefreshFragment() only from onCreate() of activity and need not be called from onResume() of activity.

Comment: ok, scroll saving is working now after I commented RefreshFragment() in activity's onResume().  However fragment is not getting refreshed after user edits fragment's fields. What should I do to make fragment's fields to update with new values?

Comment: You can keep the reference of the fragment as a member variable of the activity class and update the values through some public method.

Comment: So which method of the Fragment class should I call in the activity's onResume() on the saved instance of my fragment to make it redraw?

Comment: You will need to refactor your code to use data from getArguments on the first run and from new method after that for future updates.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think you should check if `onResume()` of `DisplayNoteActivity` is called twice too? If so, 
1. check if `requestPermission()` is invoked during `DisplayNoteActivity` launched. 
2. check if `onConfigurationChanged()` is not being handling.

If `onResume()` of `DisplayNoteActivity` is called only once, then check what's wrong with `DisplayNoteFragment`.

Comment: Thanks. I was calling requestPermission() in onViewCreated() due to which onResume() was called, then onPause() and then again onResume(). As I already had the permission, the permission dialog was not shown but of course methods called,

Comment: You are welcome.
You should check your permission first use `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()`, invoke `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` only if permissions are not granted.